# Where is the item folder located for Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I want to ask where is the location of items folder [hero items] for using customized hero images, etc?

Comment: Do you want to add a custom skin or what kind of folders are you searching exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in more length on the [Gamepedia DOTA 2 page for customizing game files](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Help:Game_Files). All of these paths are relative to your Dota 2 installation folder, so if your Steam library installs inside the Steam folder and Steam is installed in its default location all of these paths will be prefixed with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\dota 2\dota` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\dota` if you initially installed the game during beta:

- Cosmetic item data: `scripts\items\items_game.txt`
- Cosmetic item icons: `resource\flash2\images\econ`
- Interface customizations: `materials\console\loadingscreens`, `resource\flash3\images\hud_skins` and `resource\flash3\images\emoticons`
- Game assets: `resource\flash3\images`
- Hero images: `resource\flash3\images\heroes`

Note these locations may not physically exist on the filesystem as Dota 2 uses VPK files to store all of their data, this means you will need to create the relevant folders if you wish to override the VPK files.